# Explanation of 1 mod 3

Tags: math, division, modulo

So i've been looking into modulo recently. I'm trying to improve my math skills, which are not the best if i'm honest. But something i am trying to improve. I understand how this works i think. I am also quite competent with long division. However something is bugging me and i can't seem to find an answer for it online.

I know that 7 % 5 = 2 (5 goes into 7 once, with a remainder of 2).

What i don't understand is this;

1 % 3 = 1

How can this be, 3 goes into 1, 0 times, with a remainder of 3? Surely the answer to 1 % 3 = 3?

Can anyone explain this in its most simplest terms please?

Am i correct in thinking that if the dividend (1) is less than the devisor (3) which we know will equal 0 remainder x, it just uses the dividend as the result?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The answer could never be 3 since the remainder is always less than the divisor. Just run it through your head: You have one. You take the three out of it zero times. You're left with one.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what im saying my question, when the dividend is less than the devisor the result will still be the dividend. like 2 % 3 = 2

Comment: Yes. So 1 % 3 = 1 exactly the same way.

Comment: three goes into 1, 0 remainder 1; not remainder 3.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a math question, not a programming question

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The remainder in `1%3` refers to what remains of `1` (not `3`) after you divide by `3`. As you have already said, `3` goes into `1` zero times. So -- when you remove `0` multiples of `3` from `1`, all of `1` remains. Thus `1 % 3 = 1`.

Answer (score 13):

The result of a modulo operation `n % m` is just that number `r` for which `q * m + r = n` (`q` may be anything). The only requirement we have is that `0 <= r < m`.

So for instance:

```
7 % 5 --> 1 * 5 + 2 == 7 --> r = 2
1 % 3 --> 0 * 3 + 1 == 1 --> r = 1
```

Comment: Sorry as i said, my maths is not the best i dont fully understand. My thinking is clearly wrong but in my head i am doing 1 / 3, if i was to write this out as long division i would get 0 r 3, as modulos gets the remainder i still do not fully understand how the answer is not 3.